# Use JavaScript variable as route argument

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I try to add `$(this).prev("input").val()` in my id argument for an API route, but I don't know how to stop the C# part , I thought about `<text></text>` or `@:` but doesn't work like this.

Anyone has a trick ? (thought about writting the URL instead of using the RouteURL function but I don't think it's a good way to program)

```
$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.RouteUrl("IsTranslated", new { id = <text>$(this).prev("input").val()</text> }, new {market=@ViewBag.market })

 // [...]
})
```

Comment: You can't mix razor, asp tags, and JavaScript like this. They run at completely different times.

Comment: ok so I am gonna write the full URL for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't inject a JavaScript value like that (remember, the Razor code is evaluated server-side). What you can do is use your helper to build a "template" string, and replace the id value:

```
var template = '@Url.RouteUrl("IsTranslated", new { id = 0 }, new { market=@ViewBag.market })';

var id = $(this).prev("input").val();

var url = template.replace('id=0', 'id='+id);

$.ajax({
   url: url
   // [...]
})
```

This assumes, of course, that a querystring value is generated by the helper. If not, this *might* work:

```
var template = '@Url.RouteUrl("IsTranslated", new {}, new { market=@ViewBag.market })';

var id = $(this).prev("input").val();

var url = template.replace('IsTranslated', 'IsTranslated?id='+id);

$.ajax({
   url: url
   // [...]
})
```